How to prevent transitive dependencies from being downloaded in .NET?
I am building projects using Stepwise planner from Semantic Kernel 1.12.0 and running into issues while deploying code via Azure Devops pipeline.I am currently locked into using a local feed which does not have Npgsql package which is loaded as a transitive dependency.
Microsoft.KernelMemory.Core transitively refers to many packages like Npgsql which may not end up being used. I currently have a requirement where I am unable to use this package as my build pipelines while using dotnet restore task raise a security issue for a version of this package. Even going forward, I do not want to take the responsibility of updating all package versions for any security issues that may occur.
Is there a way to mark project so that some specific dependencies are not restored from dotnet restore? or
How do I mark  this transitive dependency as not needed to be downloaded? Or any other way to bypass this issue?
